# Replace a line with slashes in a file using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I am trying to replace a line in a text file using shell script
The line in the file is `path=/home/new/abc/xyz` and i have to change it to `path=/arun/old`
I want to use shell script to do this.
I have tried like

```
sed -i /path=/home/new/abc/xyz/c\path=/arun/old
```

But it didn't work

Comment: What have you tried ? What have you searched ? This is one of the most common question here, have you enemy @duckduckgo ?

Comment: change `sed` delimiters to some other char not used in your content.  Think!, how would `sed` understand where the data starts or ends?

Comment: I have tried like sed -i /home#new#abc#xyz/c\arun#old.But it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-i means you need to include an input  filename, and depending on OS, you need to specify an extension for your backup file (and the input file that contains the text). The following will convert a file that contains the string you want to convert (test.txt):

```
path=/home/new/abc/xyz to /arun/old
```

Using this command:

```
sed -i '.bak' 's#/home/new/abc/xyz#/arun/old#' test.txt
```